# Include external .js file in ReactJs web project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the external .js file url belongs to the customer, so I  can't share that,
I need to include the external js file, and call the function from that external js file. I have seen some solution like:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;   //(This is external js url)
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But it is not working for me, or may be I don't know how it works

Assume this is the external sample code:

Sample code to call locally, if we manually download the file and import

```
  let conn = demo("url", false)
  conn.login("username", "myPassword")
```

How to do same above call after including in the reactjs

```
 export default function demo (end, sec) {  
    const login = (user, password) => {
            console.log(" sending login message")

    }
   
    const logout = async (user) => {
                    console.log(" sending logout message")
    }


    /*
     * Expose these methods to the client
     */
    return { login, logout }
}
```

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668

Answer (score 1):

You will need to append your snippet in one lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` so *React* can mount it (or load) whenever you component has been mounted. Once is done, you could call the custom method.

If you use class component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;   //(This is external js url)
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() { 
    return null;
  }
}
```

Or if you use functional component with hooks

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;   //(This is external js url)
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: After loading ur external script it should run automatically. If your methods are exposed in the proper context, it should work. Unfortunately, I believe your methods are exposed on in the React context, so you will have to expose them to the window object.  Before the return, you could do something like `window.login = (...arg) => login(...arg);`

Answer (score 0):

To add the external js, there are two option

1. Create an custom script and add the js file asynchronously.
2. Use third party node module

Below are Script-

```
const addExternalJs = () => {
   const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "/<path1>/<path2>/yourJSFile.js";
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();

  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

1. Functional Based Component

   useEffect(() => {
   addExternalJs();
   }, []);
2. Class Based Component

   componentDidMount() {
   addExternalJs();
   }

Comment: thanks, but I still didn't get how call the methods from that external js file

Comment: @u_pendra when javascript files will gets loaded, you will be able to find their all function.